# Strpos 2 variables

Tags: php, strpos

I want to check `$string` for 2 words , my condition should have the 2 words not only 1

I used the following code but it work only if it has at least 1 variables

```
if ((strpos($string,'Good') || strpos($string,'Excellent')) === true) {
    $pid= '1';
} else { 
    $pid= '0'; 
} 

echo $pid;
```

Any idea to make it check the 2 variables at same time?

Comment: You've wrapped them both in parentheses but put an **or** statement between them. So obviously you're checking whether either of them match, not both.

Comment: `strpos()` will not ever return `true`. It will either return an integer or `false`.

Comment: @Qirel `=== true` is the evaluation of `( $a || $b )`.

Comment: That's true - but I believe OP is trying to check if the string contains either `Good` or `Excellent`, which fails for two reasons: `strpos()` returning `false`, and that you need to check each one individually and cannot check both in a manner of `($a || $b)`. miken's answer below sums it pretty much up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Important to remember that [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns the index of the string, which can be zero, which evaluates to false if you're not checking properly. Always compare strictly  and dont use an **or** operator when you want to check if **both** conditions are true.

```
if (strpos($string,'Good') !== false && strpos($string,'Excellent') !== false) {
    $pid= '1';
} else { 
    $pid= '0'; 
}
```

Or, more succinctly using a [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$pid = (strpos($string,'Good') !== false && strpos($string,'Excellent') !== false) ? 1 : 0;
```

---

Just to expand on the use of `strpos`, consider this code, which returns "no," because "Good" is at the zeroth position.

```
$string = "Good morning";
if (strpos($string, "Good")) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

From the manual:

> #### Warning
>
> This function may return Boolean **`FALSE`**, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to **`FALSE`**. Please read the section on [Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more information. Use [the === operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for testing the return value of this function.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace || with &&, even though regexes can help you become more specific, allowing to consider capitals and word boundaries.